# Programming in Enlightenment Window Manager

Tags: window-managers

¿Has anyone programmed in this window manager? ¿How was your experience? Oh, and besides the e17 official tuts & docs, ¿is there any other source for tutorials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're talking about programming within the Enlightenment window manager, then it seems to me it's just a matter of getting it all set up right. Each Linux distro (assuming that's what you're using) should have some sort of documentation for getting the e17 environment set up. Then it's no different from working in Gnome or KDE, really (well, slightly different, but you get the idea).

I'm actually going to assume that you're talking about the Enlightenment Foundation Libraries, however, and programming with them? If that's the case, from my experience tinkering around with them, documentation outside of their website is few and far between. However, within their website, I found the following to be most helpful:

- Their EWL tutorial and overview PDF (EWL is their widget toolkit)
- Their EFL Cookbook
- Looking at the [code](http://trac.enlightenment.org/e/browser/trunk) for some of their applications can give you a good idea of best practices, etc (my lack of rep prevents me from linking to the two PDF's I mentioned, but they can be found in the DOCS folder of the source).

HTH.

Comment: Thank you brak! I had actually given up hope of someone answering this question. BTW, I was talking about EFL :)

Answer (score 2):

- EWL is totally outdated. Use elementary instead if you want a widget toolkit
- the EFL cookbook is outdated as well.

I think the reference to read is the trac wiki: http://trac.enlightenment.org/e/wiki and the small apps around, check out the GAMES directory in the subversion repo for fun stuff.